# ios in app purchase for coupons

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm creating an app that sells coupons for other companies. For every coupon I sell I can get around 10 percents commission. 
My problem is this: using apple **in app purchase** forces me to pay 30 percents of every purchase that is made through my app. but every coupon I sell pays most of the money to the real company, while I get only 10 percents, and apple gets 30 percents. I want apple to get only 30 percents of my share - I also think it makes more sense.
What should I do? Can I use other services instead?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is wrong. Apple only considers upgrades to the app or its usage to require In-App purchase. Sales of items not installed in the app are perfectly fine but you must use an external payment system or supply your own (if you collect money). For example, an app that sells couches or rents hotel rooms is not something you need In App purchase from Apple. A virtual couch for your Farmville farm would require In App Purchase support and giving Apple 30%. Note if you offer coupons and put them into Passbook this is not enhancing the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

The *Developer Program License Agreement* forbids you from using "other services instead":

> **3.3.3** Without Apple’s prior written approval or as permitted under Section 3.3.23 (In App Purchase API), an Application may not provide, unlock or enable additional features or functionality through distribution mechanisms other than the App Store.

If you're going to sell a product through an app, you need to do it through In App Purchase.

But the *Additional Terms for Use of the In App Purchase API* (Attachment 2) pretty much forbid you from selling external things like coupons with In App Purchase:

> **1.1** You may use the In App Purchase API only to enable end users to purchase content,functionality, or services that You make available for use within Your Application (e.g. digitalbooks, additional game levels, access to a turn-by-turn map service). You may not use the InApp Purchase API to offer goods or services to be used outside of Your Application.

So it's unlikely your app will be approved in the first place. But if it is, you're still going to have to pay 30% of the *price of the product* (not your share) to Apple.

Comment: Maybe they obtained prior written approval from Apple? Or maybe, as @ahwulf suggests, 3.3.3 only addresses virtual additions to your app, and not real-world things like coupons. But I'd be cautious either way. Remember that the Kindle app originally tried to sell books outside of the Apple ecosystem (through Amazon.com), and Apple blocked it until they removes all references to the web site. This is a dangerous gray area to be making assumptions in.